# Change bgcolor of textbox without using ID in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 4 `textbox` in a `div`. I want to set the `background color` for the 3rd textbox. But, there is no `ID` attribute for the all textbox.

How to set the background color to the textbox without using the id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [eq selector](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/).

> Select the element at index n within the matched set.Zero-based index of the element to match.

```
$('div input:eq(2)').css('background-color' , 'grey');
```